# Need solution for CASE for the below result

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table say Employee

```
Employee
Emp_ID Emp_ver_ID Emp_name
   1       1        A
   1       2        AB
   2       3        C
   2       4        CD



Sales_Emp
Emp_Ver_ID   Sales_ID 
   1             1      
   2             2
   3             3



Sales
Sales_ID  Sales_name  sales_value
    1          X          XX
    2          Y          YY
    3          Z          ZZ
```

now i want a result like

```
Emp_ID  X       Y       Z
    1   XX      YY      null
    2   null    null    ZZ
```

Comment: this is unclear as to what you are asking, also show what you have tried so far

Comment: hope this example should be clear about wat kind of result i want

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I used case statement and I am getting reslut like 
Emp_Id    X     Y      Z
     1         XX  null   null
      1        null   YY    null
      2         null  null   ZZ

Comment: I dont want 2 rows for EMP_ID =1. the result should be shown in a single row..

Comment: Seems that you want to make columns from rows (creating sort of pivot table). Google for PIVOT and ORACLE, and see links like https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1, http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pivot_examples.htm

Answer (score 1):

This query using `pivot` operator (available from Oracle 11g version) gives expected output for your examples:

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b150d/1)</sup>

```
select * 
  from (
    select emp_id, sales_name, sales_value 
      from employee e 
      left join sales_emp se using (emp_ver_id)
      left join sales using (sales_id))
pivot (max(sales_value) for sales_name in ('X' x, 'Y' y, 'Z' z))
```

... and this is solution for Oracle 10g and older versions:

```
select 
    emp_id,
    max(case when sales_name = 'X' then sales_name end) x,
    max(case when sales_name = 'Y' then sales_name end) y,
    max(case when sales_name = 'Z' then sales_name end) z
  from (
    select emp_id, sales_name, sales_value
      from employee e
      left join sales_emp se using (emp_ver_id)
      left join sales using (sales_id))
  group by emp_id
```